# Sencha Touch Generate App on mac doesn't work

Tags: extjs, cmd, touch

I know Sencha is hard to learn, but I can't even get to first base and generate a starting App and I'm sure I'm not the only one!!! I have downloaded Sencha Touch SDK 2.3.1 (latest version) and Sencha CMD 5.0.1 (latest version). I have navigated to the Sencha Touch directory and typed in the command EVERYONE says to use to generate an app which is: sencha generate app MyApp ../MyApp  On my mac I get errors as Sencha CMD tries to install the working directory and the SDK files. Is this a mac problem or am I missing something here?

Here is what I get:

```
[ERR] Directory /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/touch not recognized as a framework
[ERR] Directory /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/touch not recognized as a framework
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[INF] Loading app json manifest...
[INF] Concatenating output to file /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/build/temp/production/myApp/sencha-compiler/cmd-packages.js
[INF] writing content to /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/MyApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/MyApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/MyApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] appending content to /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/MyApp/bootstrap.js
[INF] Appending content to /Users/Adam/Documents/Websites/MyApp/bootstrap.json
```

Also, the build and touch directories don't end up in the MyApp directory but instead one level up. So frustrating. Any help from anyone familiar with Sencha would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I totally understand your frustration - 2 days is a long time to be stuck. Sencha can be so confusing....big learning curve!

In this situation you are better off changing your generate app command to specify the path to the touch directory and before generating the app, I would suggest you ensure you haven't already accidentally created an app in the websites folder, as this will throw you another error.

So, assuming your directory structure has websites/touch and you want your application generated in websites/myapp, I would suggest the following:

1. Ensure you are in your websites directory
2. check for hidden .sencha folder by typing ls -a
3. if it exists, remove it by typing rm -r .sencha
4. Create the folder you wish to generate your app into (eg: myapp)
5. change to that directory (cd myapp)
6. generate your app (sencha -sdk ../touch generate app MyTestApp .)

note: "../touch" is pointing to the touch directory in the parent folder
note: "MyTestApp ." is telling the system to generate an app called MyTestApp in the current folder.

See how you go with this - hope it helps!